# I don't understand 'new string' and the [i] over here

Tags: c#

So i don't understand the 'new string' over here. I've tried reading up on it but i couldn't find any concrete answers that are simple to understand. what's the difference between string and new string?

```
 public class MainClass {
      public static void Main (string[] args) {

      Console.Write("\nInput number of students: ");
      var totalstudents = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        var name = new string [totalstudents];
        var grade = new int [totalstudents];
```

My program won't compile became of unexpected symbol 'name' and 'grade' which i think may be connected to [i] which i also don't understand.

```
  for (int i =0 ; i<totalstudents ; i++)
        {
         Console.WriteLine("\nInput student name: ")
          name[i] = Console.ReadLine(); 
         Console.WriteLine("\nInput student grade: ")
          grade[i] = int.parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

  foreach(var gradesof in grade)
   { 
    Console.WriteLine(gradesof);
   }

  }
}

}
```

Comment: the `var name = new string[totalstudents];` is the declaration of an array of strings with a `totalstudents` number of elements. If you're getting an unexpected symbol error it suggests that you are trying to use those variables out of scope. We'd need to see the complete method to see what's wrong.

Comment: @JonathonChase This is the complete `Main` method, it's just split in the middle.

Comment: @Zer0 Yeah, my mistake - I was looking at the C# and Java tags at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the `new string[...]` is creating an array.

Your compile problems include...

The lines:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nInput student name: ")
Console.WriteLine("\nInput student grade: ")
```

…are both missing a semicolon `;` at the end

Also:

```
grade[i] = int.parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

…parse should be `Parse`.

Comment: I believe the other answer provided a more precise answer to your questions about the language syntax, namely what are "new string" and "[I]".

Comment: could you tell me what the [i] is here? the video im using to teach myself mentioned something of 'index' and arrays.

Comment: @TübaËs Please see Olivier's answer, and understand what he's telling you. You should also accept it as the answer, I'm just happy to help with the other issues.

Answer (score 2):

`string` is a string. `string[]` is an array of strings, i.e. an object consisting of indexable string elements.

```
string s = "hello"; // Declares and initializes a string.

string[] a = new string[3]; // Declares and initializes a string array of length 3.
                            // Every element of the array is `null` so far.

// Fill the array with meaningful values.
a[0] = "hello";
a[1] = "world";
a[2] = "!";
```

You can also use an array intializer to get the same result:

```
string[] a = new string[] { "hello", "world", "!" };
```

You can retrieve a single element like this:

```
string world = a[1];
```

Loop through an array with `for`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine($"a[{i}] = \"{a[i]}\"");
}
```

An array can be of any type, like the `grade` array in your example being of type `int[]`.

See: [Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/)